# How to adjust datatables DOM elements

Tags: datatables

I have 2 questions:

1. Anyone knows how to make the search bar and label in one line? (red circle) Currently its 2 lines.
   Preferably using the `dom` attribute, if possible. Or any other simple and quick method.
2. How to remove the space between table header and body? (yellow space). `css`, `js` methods are welcomed!
   [image]
   Here's my datatables initialization:

```
table = $('#serviceItemList').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    scrollResize: false,
    scrollY: 300,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging: false,
    info: false,
    createdRow: function (row, data, dataIndex) {
        $(row).attr('data-id', data.id);
    },
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    ajax: {
        'url': "/serviceitem/list",
        'type': "POST",
        'data': function (data) {
            data.zone = zone;
        }
    },
    columns: [
        { data: 'checkbox', name: 'items[]' },
        { data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'DT_RowIndex' },
        { data: 'zone', name: 'zone', orderable: true, },
        { data: 'code', name: 'code', orderable: true, },
        { data: 'description', name: 'description', searchable: true },
    ],
    select: {
        style: 'multi',
        selector: 'td:first-child'
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try it by inspecting the element and look for its class name and then you can set the display property to none
and for the search bar do the same and set the float property to left

Comment: Can you share some code on how to achieve these? Thanks!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).